# SQL database Update method not working in JavaEE Web application

Tags: java, sql, servlets

My UpdateProducts Method to Update products in my SQL Table from my Web Application is not working and I can't find out why. I'm really confused as I've copied the code from a previous working example and have just changed the database it connects to (I have changed the necessary code in the Servlet (ProductAdminController) and Model (ProductDB) and I just can not get this UpdateMethod to work. The database does not contain any foreign keys that would hinder this method and my displayProducts/displayProduct and deleteProduct methods work. It's just my UpdateProduct method that will not work. Whenever I click the update button it gives me this error:

```
"type Exception report

 message

 description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

 exception

 java.lang.NullPointerException
 sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1017)
 java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:540)
 music.admin.ProductAdminController.updateProduct(ProductAdminController.java:111)
 music.admin.ProductAdminController.doPost(ProductAdminController.java:64)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
 org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
 org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
 note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.0.3 logs"
```

I've looked for obvious errors and can't find any.

ProductAdminController

```
import java.io.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import music.business.Product;
import music.data.ProductDB;

public class ProductAdminController extends HttpServlet {


   @Override
   public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {



    // get current action
    String action = request.getParameter("action");
    if (action == null) {
        action = "displayProducts";  // default action
    }

    String requestURI = request.getRequestURI();
    String url = "/index.jsp";
    if (action.equals("displayProducts")) {
        url = displayProducts(request, response);
    } else if (action.equals("displayProduct")) {
        url = displayProduct(request, response);
    } else if (action.equals("addProduct")) {
        url = "/product.jsp";
    } else if (action.equals("deleteProduct")) {
        url = deleteProduct(request, response);
    }
    getServletContext()
            .getRequestDispatcher(url)
            .forward(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse  response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    // get current action
    String action = request.getParameter("action");
    if (action == null) {
        action = "displayProducts";  // default action
    }
    String requestURI = request.getRequestURI();
    // perform action and set URL to appropriate page
    String url = "/index.jsp";
    if (action.equals("updateProduct")) {
        url = updateProduct(request, response);
    } else if (action.equals("deleteProduct")) {
        url = deleteProduct(request, response);
    }
    getServletContext()
            .getRequestDispatcher(url)
            .forward(request, response);
    }

    private String displayProducts(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) {

    List<Product> products = ProductDB.selectProducts();
    request.setAttribute("products", products);
    return "/products.jsp";
    }

    private String displayProduct(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) {

    String productCode = request.getParameter("productCode");
    Product product;
    if (productCode == null || productCode.isEmpty()) {
        product = new Product();
    } else {
        product = ProductDB.selectProduct(productCode);
    }

    request.setAttribute("product", product);
    return "/product.jsp";
    }

    private String addProduct(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) {

    return "/product.jsp";
}

private String updateProduct(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) {

    String Code = (String) request.getParameter("Code");
    String description = (String) request.getParameter("Description");
    String priceString = (String) request.getParameter("Cost");

    double price;
    try {
        price = Double.parseDouble(priceString);
        System.out.print(price);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

        price = 0;
    }

    Product product = (Product) request.getAttribute("product");
    if (product == null) {
        product = new Product();
    }
    product.setCode(Code);
    product.setDescription(description);
    product.setPrice(price);
    request.setAttribute("product", product);

    String message = "";
    if (product.getPrice() <= 0) {
        message = "You must enter a positive number for the price without "
                + "any currency symbols.";
    }
    if (product.getDescription().length() == 0) {
        message = "You must enter a description for the product.";
    }
    if (product.getCode().length() == 0) {
        message = "You must enter a code for the product.";
    }
    request.setAttribute("message", message);

    String url;
    if (message.isEmpty()) {
        if (ProductDB.selectProduct(product.getCode()) != null) {
            ProductDB.updateProduct(product);
        } else {
            ProductDB.insert(product);
        }
        url = displayProducts(request, response);
    } else {
        url = "/product.jsp";
    }
    return url;
}

private String deleteProduct(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) {

    String productCode = request.getParameter("productCode");
    Product product = ProductDB.selectProduct(productCode);
    request.setAttribute("product", product);

    String url;
    String yesButton = request.getParameter("yesButton");
    if (yesButton != null) {
        ProductDB.delete(product);
        url = displayProducts(request, response);
    } else {
        url = "/confirm_product_delete.jsp";
    }
    return url;
}    
}
```

ProductDB class

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import music.business.Product;

/**
*
* @author J

public class ProductDB {
public static int insert(Product product) {
    ConnectionPool pool = ConnectionPool.getInstance();
    Connection connection = pool.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps = null;

    String query
            = "INSERT INTO Products (Code, Description, Cost) "
            + "VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
    try {
        ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        ps.setString(1, product.getCode());
        ps.setString(2, product.getDescription());
        ps.setDouble(3, product.getPrice());
        return ps.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        return 0;
    } finally {
        DBUtil.closePreparedStatement(ps);
        pool.freeConnection(connection);
    }
}

public static int updateProduct(Product product) {
    ConnectionPool pool = ConnectionPool.getInstance();
    Connection connection = pool.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps = null;

    String query = "UPDATE Products SET "
            + "Description = ?, "
            + "Cost = ? "
            + "WHERE Code = ?";
    try {
        ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        ps.setString(1, product.getCode());
        ps.setString(2, product.getDescription());
        ps.setDouble(3, product.getPrice());

        return ps.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        return 0;
    } finally {
        DBUtil.closePreparedStatement(ps);
        pool.freeConnection(connection);
    }
}

public static int delete(Product product) {
    ConnectionPool pool = ConnectionPool.getInstance();
    Connection connection = pool.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps = null;

    String query = "DELETE FROM Products "
            + "WHERE Code = ?";
    try {
        ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        ps.setString(1, product.getCode());

        return ps.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        return 0;
    } finally {
        DBUtil.closePreparedStatement(ps);
        pool.freeConnection(connection);
    }
}

public static boolean emailExists(String code) {
    ConnectionPool pool = ConnectionPool.getInstance();
    Connection connection = pool.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    String query = "SELECT Code FROM Products "
            + "WHERE Code = ?";
    try {
        ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        ps.setString(1, code);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        return rs.next();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        return false;
    } finally {
        DBUtil.closeResultSet(rs);
        DBUtil.closePreparedStatement(ps);
        pool.freeConnection(connection);
    }
}

   public static Product selectProduct(String productCode) {
    ConnectionPool pool = ConnectionPool.getInstance();
    Connection connection = pool.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    String query = "SELECT * FROM Products "
            + "WHERE Code = ?";
    try {
        ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        ps.setString(1, productCode);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
            Product p = new Product();
            p.setCode(rs.getString("Code"));
            p.setDescription(rs.getString("Description"));
            p.setPrice(rs.getDouble("Cost"));
            return p;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
        return null;
    } finally {
        DBUtil.closeResultSet(rs);
        DBUtil.closePreparedStatement(ps);
        pool.freeConnection(connection);
    }
}
       //This method returns null if a product isn't found.
public static Product selectProduct(long productID) {
    ConnectionPool pool = ConnectionPool.getInstance();
    Connection connection = pool.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    String query = "SELECT * FROM Products "
            + "WHERE Code = ?";
    try {
        ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        ps.setLong(1, productID);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
            Product p = new Product();
            p.setCode(rs.getString("Code"));
            p.setDescription(rs.getString("Description"));
            p.setPrice(rs.getDouble("Cost"));
            return p;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
        return null;
    } finally {
        DBUtil.closeResultSet(rs);
        DBUtil.closePreparedStatement(ps);
        pool.freeConnection(connection);
    }
}

//This method returns null if a product isn't found.
public static List<Product> selectProducts() {
    ConnectionPool pool = ConnectionPool.getInstance();
    Connection connection = pool.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    String query = "SELECT * FROM Products";
    try {
        ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        ArrayList<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
        while (rs.next()) {
            Product p = new Product();
            p.setCode(rs.getString("Code"));
            p.setDescription(rs.getString("Description"));
            p.setPrice(rs.getDouble("Cost"));
            products.add(p);
        }
        return products;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
        return null;
    } finally {
        DBUtil.closeResultSet(rs);
        DBUtil.closePreparedStatement(ps);
        pool.freeConnection(connection);
    }
}
```

}

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

JSP Product code

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="utf-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="jr" uri="/WEB-INF/murach.tld" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Product Maintenance</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value='/styles/main.css'/> ">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Product</h1>
   <p><jr:ifEmptyMark color="blue" field=""/> marks required fields</p>

    <p><i>${message}</i></p>

    <form action="<c:url value='/productMaint'/>" 
          method="post" class="inline">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="updateProduct">

        <label class="pad_top">Code:</label>
        <input type="text" name="productCode" id="codeBox" value="${product.code}">
        <jr:ifEmptyMark color="blue" field="${product.code}"/><br>


        <label class="pad_top">Description:</label>
        <input type="text" name="description" 
               value="${product.description}">
        <jr:ifEmptyMark color="blue" field="${product.description}"/><br>

        <label class="pad_top">Price:</label>
        <input type="text" name="price" id="priceBox"
               value="${product.priceNumberFormat}">
        <jr:ifEmptyMark color="blue" field="${product.priceNumberFormat}"/><br>

        <label class="pad_top">&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="submit" value="Update Product" class="margin_left">
     </form>

     <form action="<c:url value='/productMaint'/>" 
          method="get" class="inline">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="displayProducts">
        <input type="submit" value="View Products">
     </form>

     </body>
     </html>
```

Found my problem finally!! Can't believe how it was just about right in my face and I didn't catch on earlier!

```
    String Code = (String) request.getParameter("Code");
    String description = (String) request.getParameter("Description");
    String priceString = (String) request.getParameter("Cost");

    product.setCode(Code);
    product.setDescription(description);
    product.setPrice(price);
    request.setAttribute("product", product);
```

Should be:

```
    String productCode = (String) request.getParameter("productCode");
    String description = (String) request.getParameter("description");
    String priceString = (String) request.getParameter("price");

    product.setCode(productCode);
    product.setDescription(description);
    product.setPrice(price);
    request.setAttribute("product", product);
```

Comment: Value for priceString is null

Answer (score 0):

```
String query = "UPDATE Products SET "
        + "Description = ?, "
        + "Cost = ? "
        + "WHERE Code = ?";
try {
    ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
    ps.setString(1, product.getCode());
    ps.setString(2, product.getDescription());
    ps.setDouble(3, product.getPrice());
```

i think it should be

```
   try {
    ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
    ps.setString(1, product.getDescription());
    ps.setString(2, product.getPrice());
    ps.setDouble(3, product.getCode());
```

I see wrong parameters passed in the update Query

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with Cost value you get in updateProduct method[ProductAdminController.java].

Appears you don't get any value for cost parameter, "price = Double.parseDouble(priceString)" resulting into NullPointerException exception.

Try printing value for:
    String priceString = (String) request.getParameter("Cost");

Comment: MXrider19 - Go through this info and let us know value for priceString.

Comment: When I debug at: String priceString = (String) request.getParameter("Cost"); It shows the values that I entered on my web app for the code, description and cost but directly afterwards at my print statement it says: priceString = null

Comment: Please post complete jsp code from where you submit request.

Comment: Will do, I've added it to my question above

Comment: Could you please check what you get for below parameter: `code` String priceString = (String) request.getParameter("priceNumberFormat");

Comment: Still says priceString = null. I seriously don't get how it works with the one database and not the other, very confusing.